# Transition Causes Elements with Opacity to Disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've found an odd bug whilst trying to create a toggleable sidebar. I have a set of social media icons with the following code to make them change opacity on hover:

```
.snIcons {
    filter: opacity(.4);
    -webkit-filter: opacity(.4);
    -o-filter: opacity(.4);
    -moz-filter: opacity(.4);
    -ms-filter: opacity(.4);
    transition: 0.3s filter linear;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s -webkit-filter linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s -moz-filter linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s -ms-filter linear;
    -o-transition: 0.3s -o-filter linear;
}

.snIcons:hover {
    filter: opacity(1);
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
    -o-filter: opacity(1);
    -moz-filter: opacity(1);
    -ms-filter: opacity(1);
    transition: 0.3s filter linear;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s -webkit-filter linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s -moz-filter linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s -ms-filter linear;
    -o-transition: 0.3s -o-filter linear;
}
```

In the HTML they are laid out like this:

```
<div class="sidebar-footer">

              <a href="https://twitter.com/PixcelDev"><img class="snIcons" src="Images/twitter.png"/></a>
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pixcelstudios"><img class="snIcons" src="Images/facebook.png"/></a>
              <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/pixcelstudios"><img class="snIcons" src="Images/linkedin.png"/></a>
              <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/Pixcel_Studios/"><img class="snIcons" src="Images/reddit.png"/></a>
              <br>
              <a href="https://instagram.com/pixceldev/"><img class="snIcons" src="Images/instagram.png"/></a>
              <a href="https://www.behance.net/pixcelstudios"><img class="snIcons" src="Images/behance.png"/></a>
              <a href="https://github.com/Pixceldev"><img class="snIcons" src="Images/github.png"/></a>
              <a href="http://pixceldev.deviantart.com/"><img class="snIcons" src="Images/deviantart.png"/></a>
              <h3>Copyright Joeb Rogers

</div>
```

I'm using the following jQuery to hide certain elements of my sidebar on click:

```
$("#collapse").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar-nav").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".sidebar-footer").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("collapsed");
    $(".sidebar-head").toggleClass("collapsed");
});
```

They appear fine in the first place and everything works well and good. However, once I toggle the sidebar to disappear and then toggle it back to full size, only two of the icons appear. When I hover over where they were supposed to be, they reappear. It seems like somehow by toggling `display: none` and then back to normal it messes up with their initial opacity state and sets it to 0, but it says it's set to 0.4 still in the inspector.

The weird part is, when I removed the break in the html and tried it again, a different two icons were visible (two next to each other) whereas normally it's the two that are opposite each other vertically.

Anybody have any idea how to fix this other than to remove the opacity? Thanks!

EDIT: I've made the discovery that it has to do with toggling the size of the sidebar rather than the display type. When I toggle the sidebar, it goes from fullscreen to 80px and back again (mobile). I just changed it to 60px and upon toggling back none of the icons were visible. I believe that if the size of the container gets smaller than their position then their opacity messes up. No idea why, I tried changing the .hidden class to `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none` but there was no change.

EDIT 2: Okay, so I've debugged the issue down to the transition effect I'm using for changing the sidebar's size. Because I'm changing the display on click, the elements are being created again before the container is large enough (transition takes 0.3 seconds). This for some reason means they are not being rendered. Anyone know any fixes that could help this?

Comment: This is a lot to read. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by using `fadeToggle("slow")` instead of toggleClass, could not tell you why this made such a difference.